# 1 Dimensional Sobel Produces Noise

Tags: c++, edge-detection, sobel

I'm attempting a piece-by-piece Sobel edge detector for a project for school, and I can't wrap my head around where I am going wrong. Without putting up too much detail, I think a large portion of it boils down to the code below. When I put a lenna.pgm image:

[image]

through for a 2D mask along the x-gradient, I get a lot of noise.

I discussed the code with my instructor, and I'm doing what he says to do.

Here's the code for the x-direction convolution:

```
void applySobel(int maskX[3][3], int maskY[3][3], int maskWidth, int imageH, int imageW, 
                                              int threshold, int*** generated){
    int sumX, sumY;

     // convolve smoothed image with Sobel mask in the X-direction
     for(int i = 0; i < imageH; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < imageW; j++) {
             if(i == 0 || i >= imageH - 1 || j == 0 || j >= imageW - 1) {
                 sumX = 0;
             } else {
                 sumX = 0;
                 for(int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
                     for(int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                         sumX += generated[0][i+x][j+y] * maskX[x+1][y+1];
                     }
                 }
             }
             generated[1][i][j] = sumX;
         }
     }
}
```

I've also tried normalizing the image before outputting to a file, but the image goes dark.

```
    for(int a = 1; a < 6; a++) {

    min = imageOUT[a][0][0];
    max = 0;
    // normalize the pixel values and then write to files
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            pixel = imageOUT[a][i][j];
            if(pixel < min) {
                min = pixel;
            } if(pixel > max) {
                max = pixel;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            imageOUT[a][i][j] = (int)(imageOUT[a][i][j] - min) * (255/(max-min));
        }
    }

    WriteImage(fileOutName[a-1].c_str(), imageOUT[a], M, N, Q);
}
```

I deeply appreciate any insight. This has been keeping me up for days now.

Comment: Does your school ask you to use C++ for pattern recognition? I recommend you to try in Matlab first then migrate to C++ if necessary.

Comment: Yes. We use C/C++ wherever possible. This assignment was also in C/C++. I should add that the convolution works for Gaussian filters that I applied to the image beforehand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can post a link to the image and someone can then check and add it in. SO works in large part by iterative editing.

Comment: Sure: http://i.imgur.com/82L05Kb.png Thank you for the welcoming.

Comment: The image is stored kind of strangely, as an `int ***`. Usually you would store images as contiguous pixels, e.g. `int *` (or `int **` for multiple images) and index using multiplication, e.g. `pixels[j*w+i]`. Also, you seem to be indexing by column first and then row - are you sure this is correct? Usually images are stored in row-major order, not column-major order.

Comment: o.o That is something I'll look in to. I'm just used to row-major C++, so I'm used to assuming that's how the world spins. I'll post if it works. Thank you. I kept the triple-pointer to keep a listing of the image as it's passed through the subsequent filters, so generated[0][row][col] holds the original with the next pointer holding the translated image and so on. We were also given a library to use that takes input this way, so it was accommodating.

Comment: TBH if I look at that image, I don't see any well-defined edges. It looks like noise to me. Texture detection might make more sense.

Comment: Sorry. The image above is the result of the pass. The fed-in image is Lenna in grayscale pgm. Just an update. I got it working by removing the loops and only coding in for the six blocks used for the mask image then normalizing those. It isn't exactly the code I would have chosen, but for the grade, I'm happy with something that works. I'll post what I have after the assignment is due for future reference. In the meantime, here's a much prettier Lenna: http://i.imgur.com/L0vXl9h.png

Comment: Please move the "UPDATE" section into an answer. Answering your own question is valid and helps others to see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Here's the solution I arrived at. Basically, I took only the objects of interest in the mask instead of multiplying and adding all of it, so the zero spaces were left out.

```
void applySobel(int maskX[3][3], int maskY[3][3], int maskWidth, int imageH, int imageW, 
                                          int threshold, int*** generated){
int sumX, sumY;

 // convolve smoothed image with Sobel mask in the X-direction
 for(int i = 0; i < imageH; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < imageW; j++) {
         if(i == 0 || i == imageH - 1 || j == 0 || j == imageW - 1) {
             sumX = generated[0][i][j];
         } else {
             sumX = (int)(generated[0][i-1][j-1]*maskX[0][0] + 
                    generated[0][i][j-1]*maskX[1][0] +
                    generated[0][i+1][j-1]*maskX[2][0] +
                    generated[0][i-1][j+1]*maskX[0][2] +
                    generated[0][i][j+1]*maskX[1][2]+
                    generated[0][i+1][j+1]*maskX[2][2])/2;
         }
         generated[1][i][j] = sumX/3;
     }
 }
```

And the beautiful Lenna after applying the X-Direction Gradient:
[image]

Thank you all very much for your suggestions.